# Unable to take screenshots

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

I have this code to take screenshots of layouts in Android. It is not throwing any errors, however, the screenshot is not being taken either. Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here? I am new with Eclipse and I am having a hard time figuring things out. Also if there is any other way to take screenshots can you post it as an answer to this thread? Thanks for your time!

```
  private void getScreenshot()
                {
                    View content = findViewById(R.id.testView);
                    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                    content.buildDrawingCache(true);

                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache());
                    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                    File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "image.png");

                    try 
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                        ostream.close();

                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    }
```

Comment: How you know the screenshot is not being taken? App crashes? an exception is thrown? the file is empty? image is corrupted? Please, be specific.

Comment: what type of `View` is content?

Comment: Did you enable `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest?

Comment: @Cristian: I checked by going into my sdcard (through Astro File Manager) after exiting the app. The file isnt there. Also, to ensure this, I went to Windows > Open perspective > DDMS > Devices > File Explorer > mnt > sdcard, and it shows that the sdcard is empty!

Comment: @slayton: Content is a "TableLayout"

Comment: @Kieran: Yes, that has been done already but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to add path separator into your File?  i.e.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
                     File.separator + "image.png");
```

You should add a lot more logs and tests in your code to check whether it is behaving as you would expect, e.g.

- Log the details of the file you are trying to create to be sure it is correct.
- Once you've created the file, test that it exists, e.g. `if (!file.exists())`
- The [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) function returns a boolean, so you should check the return value and log it to see if it succeeded.

One other thought: maybe you need to call ostream.flush() ([API docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29)) to ensure the buffered data is written to the file?

I'm assuming you're writing this code for use within your app.  You probably already know this, but DDMS provides a way to take screenshots in case you just want to take some yourself.  Just make sure to select the device to enable the Screenshot menu option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation! I finally figured what is wrong with my app....It is a whole new different issue though. My screenshot is meant to be attached to an email, but it wasnt showing since the file is too large. Any thoughts on how to make the file size smaller?

Comment: Pass a number much smaller than 100 to the compress function.  Valid values are 0 to 100:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29